# reactjs axios cant get api data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I can't get my api data from https://randomuser.me/api/

But when I'm using another api like http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees it works.

The error:

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Start from "./start";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Start />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

start.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

class Start extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then(res => {
      const results = res.data;
      this.setState({ results });
      console.log(results);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.results.map(result => {
          return <div>{result.id}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Start;
```

Comment: const results = res.data; replace const results = res.results;

Comment: What is the result of your `console.log(results)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees returns array while https://randomuser.me/api/ returns object. Try changing to

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then(res => {
      const results = res.data.results;
      this.setState({ results });
      console.log(results);
    });
  }
```

Comment: @SteFandy Be sure to always check structure of response so you can setup your code accordingly. You can accept the answer if solution resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use res.data.results. It comes in results object.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JSON data 
last line you missed the "}]" typo error in http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(res => {
      const results = res.data;
      this.setState({ results: results });
    });
  }
```